# some confusion in Rank nullity theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ U,V$ and $ W$  be finite dimensional   real  vector spaces,  $T: U→V,\;S:V→W$ and $P:W→U $ be  linear transformations. If $\operatorname{range}(ST) = \operatorname{null space} (P)$,  $\;\operatorname{null space}(ST)=\operatorname{range} P\;$  and $\operatorname{rank}(T)=\operatorname{rank}(S)$. Then  which of the following is true?

Option 1) nullity of T= nullity of S

option 2) $\dim U \neq \dim W$

option 3) if $\dim V= 3$, $\;\dim U=4$ ,then $P$ is not identically zero

option 4) If  $\dim V= 4$, $\;\dim U= 3$ and $T$ is one-one ,then $P$ is identically zero.

My thinking : By rank nullity theorem,  I got only option  1 is correct  as I don't know the other options...

Pliz help me and  I'm very confused as any hints or solution  can be appreciated.

Thank  u

Comment: @ Bernard help  me...which option is true ?

Comment: I'd love to, but it's very intricate.  Actually, I don't see how you derive option 1). All I can say is that option 2) is false. I didn't examine the last two options yet.

Comment: thanks Bernad sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can say:

- Option 2) is false. On the contrary, $\dim U=\dim W$, since
  $$\dim U=\dim (\ker ST)+\dim(\operatorname{Im}ST)=\dim(\operatorname{Im}P)+\dim (\ker P)=\dim W.$$
- Option 3) is true: if $\dim U>\dim V$, $T$ cannot be injective, nor $ST$.  Hence $$\operatorname{Im}P = \ker ST\ne\{0\}.$$

Comment: thanks a lots bernard sir